# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this SQL procedure :

```
@Month int
as
begin

select COUNT(*) as absence,employeeId from(select MONTh,DAY,employeeId,(select COUNT(*) 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) as leaveID
from employee_c c,holiday hl,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+@Month-1, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+@Month-1, -1)) 
where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (select dayId+1 from days) and (select lv.EmployeeId 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) is NULL and Date not between hl.startDate and hl.endDate and c.isActive=1 )sc group by employeeId
end
```

When I select 3 as month parameter , I got an error :

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How can I solve this error??

**Note:** For the parameter `3` , the `employee_L` have more than row  (3 rows)

The error occurs on the two queries :

```
(select lv.EmployeeId 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) is NULL
```

and

```
select COUNT(*) 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) as leaveID
```

To be more specific , I wouldn't use `TOP 1` or `count(*)` I need only to get all result from this query :

```
    select MONTH,DAY,employeeId,(select lv.EmployeeId 
from employee_l lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) from employee_c c,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2-1, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2-1, -1))
```

This the schema of the table `Employee_lv`

```
Employee_lvId         start_day         end_day           days          

     0415             2021-03-02       2021-03-01          3                         
     0785             2021-04-01       2021-04-10          10
```

If I have one row , I got only all month days exclude the days that exist in Employee_l ( for example if I choose 3 as month "March" )

Result expected:

( with one row , suppose I have only the first row ) => 31-3 =28
I will got 28 rows that are null.

But If I have two rows , I didn't got what I need.. and I got the error described in the first question!!! What can I do in this case?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results help.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are expecting

```
and (select lv.EmployeeId 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) is null
```

to only return a single row

It should be

```
and not exists (
select * 
from employee_L lv 
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you , but this does not work for me

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what 'does not work' means, you mean results not as expected or query error?

Comment: The error was disappeared but the result that I got was false, for that reason I'm telling you thank you , but this does not work for me , because I didn't got the expected result.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without more info, if you can include your tables' schema with sample data and expected results then someone could assist more.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your comments, that you want same query in both COUNT(*) and NULL check. So, you can modify NULL check as given below.

```sql
(SELECT lv.EmployeeId
            FROM employee_L lv
            WHERE DATE BETWEEN lv.start_date
                    AND lv.end_date
                AND lv.EmployeeId = c.employeeId
                AND c.isActive = 1) IS NULL
```

What you can do is:

```sql
(select COUNT(*) 
from employee_L lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) = 0
```

Comment: No , this will give false result in the other query

Comment: @csharp_devloper31, this is just conditional check for NULL. changing this query does not affect other query.

Comment: My object is to count the result of the select query , for that reason `Select top 1` will give me false result and will only return one result , so I need to count the result that I got.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31, this is not count(*) condition. this is another condition for NULL check. COUNT(*) condition is fine for subquery check as LeaveID

Comment: Yes I know but I need to count the ( select query ) , all values that eqauls null

Comment: To use it in other query

Comment: @csharp_devloper31, updated my answer. basically i use same query in both places

Comment: Unfortunately , I got the false result again